# Installing Arch are you supposed to 'choose' systemd?

Tags: linux, installation, encryption, arch-linux, systemd

I'm at the step in a new LVM on LUKS install, [Configuring mkinitcpio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Configuring_mkinitcpio)
where I'm to enter the LMV/LUKS hooks in `mkinitcpio.conf`.

Are you meant to *choose* to use `systemd`? I'm set to add the `encrypt` hook, and I feel I've skipped the step where I would know if I'm meant to be using `sd-encrypt` instead.

This is a new install on a Lenovo W541 laptop with two-disk setup (Win on SSD, and Arch on new HDD)

Answer (score 3):

The usage of systemd in the initramfs is independent from the main system. With Arch's mkinitcpio, the traditional shell-based initramfs is still the default (and somewhat better maintained than the systemd variant). Which type is used depends on what hooks you specify, and can be changed at any time after installation.

In other words, use `sd-encrypt` *only* if you've already placed `systemd` in the hook list. In all other cases, use the regular `encrypt`.

Comment: where in the install process do you choose systemd?

Comment: For the initramfs, it's not strictly part of the install process. I suggest first installing with the default type, and later if you want you can edit mkinitcpio.conf to add the `systemd` and `sd-encrypt` hooks.